# loopback4 application reads loopback3 models after migration

Tags: typescript, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback4, loopback3

I migrated my loopback3 application to loopback4, as a last step of migration, I migrated loopback3 models, but when I change my model variables in loopback4, migrated application does not read that changes, It continues to read models from loopback3. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have rebuilt the project using `npm run build` and found out the new changes are not reflected, you can try `npm run clean` before building it again.

Comment: I added those properties in my `npm start` script, when I write `npm start` it cleans project, it takes rebuild afterwards, it starts application, so I am receiving rebuilded project on my localhost.